# Mistake with receiving bool variable between two forms

Tags: c#

All.

I want to receive checkbox1 data from form1 to form2. I used get and set methods to receive meaning of variable. I used this code for this. But it didn't work. Why? Where is the problem?

form1.cs

```
...
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 test = new Form2();
            test.checkBox1 = checkBox1.Checked;
            test.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

form2.cs

```
    ...
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            private bool data7;

            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public bool checkBox1 
            {
                get { return data7; }
                set { value = data7; } 
            }

            private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (data7 == true)
                {
                    label1.Text = "true";
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "false";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
set { value = data7; }
```

should be

```
set { data7 = value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `set` method is wrong. It should be

```
set { data7 = value; }
```

`Form2` apparently stores the value in the variable `data7`, but not in a CheckBox. You would have to do something like this to actually store it in a CheckBox

```
public bool checkBox1
{
    get { return myCheckBox.Checked; }
    set { myCheckBox.Checked = value; }
}
```

Another problem is returning the result of user input to `Form1`. Since you call `Form2` with `test.Show();` the code after this statment continues immediately, without wating for `Form2` to close. Call `test.ShowDialog();` instead.

---

Another option for returning a result while not blocking `Form1` is to use an event. Using this definition

```
public class Form2ResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Form2ResultEventArgs(bool checked)
    {
        this.Checked = checked;
    }

    public bool Checked { get; private set; }
}
```

In `Form2` you would define an event like this.

```
public event EventHandler<Form2ResultEventArgs> Form2Result;

private OnForm2Result(bool checked)
{
    var handler = Form2Result;
    If (handler != null) {
        handler(this, new Form2ResultEventArgs(checked));
    }
}

// Assuming that you have a OK button on Form2
private OkButton_Click (...)
{
    OnForm2Result(myCheckBox.Checked);
    this.Close();
}
```

In Form1

```
var test = new Form2();
test.Form2Result += ProcessResult;
test.Show();

...

private void ProcessResult(object sender, Form2ResultEventArgs e)
{
    bool result = e.Checked;
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you only want to set a label, why not just do this

In Form2

```
public void SetDisplay(bool value) {
    label1.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

In Form1

```
var test = new Form2();
test.SetDisplay(checkBox1.Checked);
test.Show();
```

Note that `InitializeComponent` is called in the constructor of `Form2` and therefore the label exists after `new Form2()`. No need to do that in `Form2_Load`.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think you have over read the question quite considerably.  While your answers are correct, I don't believe you have offered anything that Fur Dworetzky has not already given.  The OP is not looking to store the variable as a checkbox, they are displaying it in a label, and they never asked to return any results to Form1, so there is no need for a showDialog.

Comment: Yes, probably. He named a property `checkBox1`, but when you assign a value to it, no checkbox is set! This is very missleading. If he only wants to set a label, why not just do this: `public void SetDisplay(bool value) { Label1.Text = value.ToString(); }`?

Comment: Agree completely very poor use of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that when the bool data7 is created that is set a value of false, or true I don't care, cause when the form is first loaded if the user has not set CheckBox1 the Form will crash. And Yes I know the OP, in the Code given, did set the variable.

```
private bool data7 = false;
```

I have included Fur Dworetzkys Answer in my suggestion Below

```
...
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        //give the variable a default value
        private bool data7=false;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool checkBox1 
        {
            get { return data7; }
            //Here is Furs Correction
            set { data7 = value; } 
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (data7 == true)
            {
                label1.Text = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not doing anything (e.g. validation) with data7 in get or set, then just get rid of them.

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
            {
                public Form2()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                public bool checkBox1 { get; set; }

                private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (checkBox1)
                    {
                        label1.Text = "true";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label1.Text = "false";
                    }
                }
            }
```